# How to reference a value of an object by property?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have an angularjs object like this:

```
$scope.afterLogin = [
    {value: 'customers|follow-ups', text: 'Follow Ups'},
    {value: '', text: 'not set'}
];
```

I'm trying to use it with [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) as follows:

```
<span
    editable-select="user.default_module"
    e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in afterLogin"
    e-name="default_module"
    e-form="rowform">{{s[user.default_module] as s.text for s in afterLogin}}</span>
```

What I am trying is to show the text-property in afterLogin that is defined by user.default_module. What am I doing wrong? I am getting parse errors on *s[user.default_module] as* - how do I reference a property of an object in this scope?

Note: this is wrapped with `ng-repeat="user in users"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display currently selected value in a very strage way. In the [official example](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#select-local) they are using filter for this purpose. However, you can simplify it by builing a `value: label` map, i.e.:

```
$scope.afterLoginLabels = {};
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.afterLogin.length; i++) {
  $scope.afterLoginLabels[$scope.afterLogin[i].value] = $scope.afterLogin[i].text;   
}
```

Then, display text value as:

```
<span [...]>{{ afterLoginLabels[user.default_module] }}</span>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/8368/).